# Integer x; is syntactic error or semantic error?

Tags: c, syntax-error, ansi-c

This is an ANSI C program. Which part of the seven-phase C compiler will throw an error?
The community is divided between Syntax Analyzer and Semantic Analyzer.

```
int main()
{
    Integer x;
    return 0;
}
```

Declaration: This question was asked in the GATE examination in 2021. It is not a part of any live examination.

Comment: Since there is no declaration of type `Integer`, which syntax rule can match a statements which consists of just two identifiers?

Comment: @qrdl a type name is also just an identifier. The grammar should happily accept wo identifiers. Semantics demand that one must be a type name that has to be defined before usage.

Comment: @Gerhardh Lexer typically can distinguish between type and non-type, and provide different token types to the parser, so no, from the parser point of view type isn't an identifier, it is a type name. You cannot create C grammar which process types and non-types in the same way.

Comment: @qrdl but type names can be refined to identifiers or struct/union/enum names. As a result of tokenization you should get 2 identifiers. One in place of a type name and one in place of a variable name. The content of the symbol table at that time should no affect grammar. Unknown type or implicit function declarations are not prevented by syntax. But I admit that it has been a long time since my compiler classes...

Comment: @Gerhardh Type name should have different token type, otherwise it just cannot match some syntax rules, such as variable declaration or type cast. Example lexer here: http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/ANSI-C-grammar-l.html#check-type

Comment: In a classical setup (e.g., lex+yacc) and in the absence of a typedef for `Integer`, `Integer` will be lexed as non-type identifier for something that hasn't been declared (=> that's a semantic error), which when followed by another undeclared identifier (=> another semantic error) gives a syntactic error. So both types or error, you could say.

Answer (score 4):

The C standard defines eight phases of translation, not seven.<sup>1</sup> Since phase 8 performs the actions traditionally performed by linkers (resolving external references and creating a program image), one might consider a compiler to consist of phases 1 to 7.

The standard does not give the phases titles such as “Syntax Analyzer” and “Semantic Analyzer.” The only phase into which detecting an error in `Integer x;` fits is phase 7, in which “The resulting tokens are syntactically and semantically analyzed and translated as a translation unit.” This can be seen because the source text shown, including `Integer x;`, can be successfully processed through phases 1 to 6: The text will obviously survive through the end of preprocessing, which is phase 4, and then phases 5 and 6 are simply conversion of characters to the execution character set and concatenation of adjacent string literals, which also pose no problem for this source text.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> C 2018 5.1.1.2, and the same in earlier versions back to C 1990.

Comment: For reference: [C11 5.1.1.2: Translation phases](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.1.2)

Comment: So, it is neither Syntax Analyzer nor Semantic Analyzer right?

Comment: Based on the list of phases in the link, I get the feeling that the seven phases mentioned in the question (incl. the two named ones), are not the same phases as the those in the linked text. Which leaves open the question of what they are, then.

Comment: They refer to those in compiler text books Lexical Analysis, syntax analysis, semantic analysis, intermediate code generation, intermediate code optimization, target code optimization, target code generation.